# Change color for each Sash in Pane Window

Tags: python, tkinter

where can I change the color for each Sash?
It will be very good to change color when sash is moving. Like highlighting.

Result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/A37Rt.png

Expected:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kd0GP.png

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class MyApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.pane = tk.PanedWindow(self, bg='green', width=1000, bd=0, sashwidth=50)
        self.pane.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.pane.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.sash_color)

        self.text_1 = tk.Text(self.pane)
        self.text_2 = tk.Text(self.pane)
        self.text_3 = tk.Text(self.pane)

        self.pane.add(self.text_1, stretch="always")
        self.pane.add(self.text_2, stretch="always")
        self.pane.add(self.text_3, stretch="always")

        self.text_1.insert("end", "TEXT 1")
        self.text_2.insert("end", "TEXT 2")
        self.text_3.insert("end", "TEXT 3")

    def sash_color(self, event):
        widget = event.widget  # get widget/paned window of event
        x, y = event.x, event.y  # get x and y coord of event
        data = widget.identify(x, y)  # paned window identify
        print("data: ", data)
        if data != '':  # identify returns empty string if child window
            sash = data[0]
            print("sash: ", sash)

app = MyApp()
app.mainloop()
```

in [tkinter docs](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/panedwindow.html) there is just bg color for all sashes, not separately.
If this is not possible is it a good solution to .place some label over it with different color and assign it to a sash motion to track it?

Comment: Simply put another `PanedWindow` in the right side, then you can set the sash color independently.

Comment: I put another but text widget 1 and 2 goes to Pane 1 and in Pane 2 cannot go with 2 and 3, because 2 is already in Pane 1. Maybe I mistaken. Can you provide example?

Answer (score 0):

If you want independent sash color, one of the way is put another `PanedWindow` into the first `PanedWindow`.

Below is an example based on yours:

```py
import tkinter as tk

class MyApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # outer PanedWindow
        self.pane = tk.PanedWindow(self, bg='green', width=1000, bd=0, sashwidth=50)
        self.pane.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # inner PanedWindow
        self.pane_2 = tk.PanedWindow(self.pane, bg='green', width=700, bd=0, sashwidth=50)

        # text box in outer PanedWindow
        self.text_1 = tk.Text(self.pane) 
        # text boxes in inner PanedWindow
        self.text_2 = tk.Text(self.pane_2) 
        self.text_3 = tk.Text(self.pane_2)

        # add first text box and the inner PanedWindow into outer PaneWindow
        self.pane.add(self.text_1, stretch="always", width=300)
        self.pane.add(self.pane_2, stretch="always", width=700)

        # add second and third text boxes into inner PanedWindow
        self.pane_2.add(self.text_2, stretch="always", width=300)
        self.pane_2.add(self.text_3, stretch="never", width=300)

        self.text_1.insert("end", "TEXT 1")
        self.text_2.insert("end", "TEXT 2")
        self.text_3.insert("end", "TEXT 3")

        # setup events binding
        for event in ("<Button-1>", "<ButtonRelease-1>"):
            self.pane.bind(event, self.sash_color)
            self.pane_2.bind(event, self.sash_color)

    def sash_color(self, event):
        # determine the sash color base on the event type
        color = "red" if event.type == tk.EventType.ButtonPress else "green"
        event.widget.config(bg=color)

app = MyApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for. I was thinking in paraller, but one pane in another is a must. Although when moving left sash a sligth faster, right sash gets shaky, but that is another story. 
Thanks @acw1668